# Telerik RadGrid Filtering on multiple columns are not working with Advanced binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I am currently working on RadGrid with *OnNeedDataSource* data binding. Filtering on this will work great only with one column at a time but not working on multiple columns. I mean, if I filter Novel Type first it works, and later if filtered for Book Type, only Book Type will get filtered but not both.
When postback happens, I am even missing the first filter criteria text in the text box.

Am I missing anything to add here?

```
<telerik:RadGrid RenderMode="Auto" runat="server" ID="RadGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" GridLines="None"
        AllowAutomaticUpdates="true" AllowAutomaticInserts="true" ShowStatusBar="true"  AllowFilteringByColumn="true" EnableLinqExpressions="false" OnItemCommand="RadGrid1_ItemCommand" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid_DataSource" OnItemCreated="RadGrid_ItemCreated" OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound"
        OnInsertCommand="RadGrid_InsertCommand" OnUpdateCommand="RadGrid_UpdateCommand" OnDeleteCommand="RadGrid_DeleteCommand">
        <ExportSettings HideStructureColumns="true">
        </ExportSettings>
        <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="false"></GroupingSettings>
        <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="CustomerProfileId" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" CommandItemDisplay="Bottom" InsertItemDisplay="Top" InsertItemPageIndexAction="ShowItemOnCurrentPage" TableLayout="Fixed">
            <CommandItemSettings ShowExportToExcelButton="true" />
            <Columns>
<telerik:GridBoundColumn 
.
.
.
```

On the serverside I have not written any code related filtering for **RadGrid1_ItemCommand**

Thank you,

ABM

Comment: knock knock... can anyone help me out here?